# how to get an image to move position along top of a div when link is clicked

Tags: javascript

I am new to all of this, and I am trying to get the image movement effect like this site has:http://www.heroku.com/.  How do I get the image to move along the div when the navigational link is clicked?

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to the origami stage images on the main page with the arrow highlight that moves along while clicking the cranes? On this very page they are using jQuery animate method, you can see the whole code in home.js file.

If you want to try and do something like that I would go for something similar, like (using jQuery):

```
$(function () {
    var slider = $('#slider'),
        first = $('.list-item').first(),
        margin = (first.outerWidth() - first.innerWidth()) / 2,
        // compute the offset for the slider
        // you will have to tailor those to your specific implementation
        offset = (slider.outerWidth() / 2) +
                 ((first.outerWidth() - slider.outerWidth()) / 2);
    // attach click event to the menu elements
    $('.list-item').on('click', function () {
        var self = $(this),
            siblings = self.siblings(),
            x;
        // if not active, move the slider accordingly
        if (!self.hasClass('active')) {
            siblings.removeClass('active');
            self.addClass('active');
            x = offset + margin + self.position().left;
            // the magic happens here :)
            slider.animate({
                left: x
            }, 500);
        }
    });
    // trigger the click event for the first list element
    first.trigger('click');
});
```

Of course earlier you have to prepare your HTML elements properly, add some styling, and play with the margins, outer/inner widths etc.

You can find my 5 minutes tutorial/example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/krwck/bjVdN/10/

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I am refering to the little blue upside down arrow that slides along the top of the container when a icon link is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

probably the best choice for that will be JQuery. you can define

```
<a class='menu'>Option 1</a>
<a class='menu'>Option 2</a>
<a class='menu'>Option 3</a>

<div id='moveable'></div>
```

than you use JQuery like this :

```
$(".menu").click(function(){
   $("#moveable").animate({

   right: '+=150',

   }, 500, function() {
   // Animation complete.
 });
});
```

You will need some CSS styling too. Hope this helps a bit.

This link may help as well : http://api.jquery.com/animate/